# Mootools Fx OnComplete Firing Before Animation Complete?

Tags: mootools

I've got a simple fiddle running a Tween animation using MooTools Fx.Tween and I can't seem to get the onComplete option to fire after the initial animation stops.  For whatever reason, it always wants to fire in the middle.  What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUWsU/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're doing it right.

I think there's a problem (basically, a 'conflict'.. you can use css transition OR js animation, not together) with `-webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0` inside `#bar` . By commenting/removing it, it's working properly -> http://jsfiddle.net/vPuAR/